# Auto fill find bar with highlighted text?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

When searching on the page it would be great if you could auto fill the find bar with highlighted text as was proposed here:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/sS43zI263q0

Is there already an extension that does this?

Comment: If you're asking whether an extension exists, this is off-topic here. If you're asking how to write such an extension, please modify your question to reflect this.

Comment: @Xan I guess I'm off topic, which is the correct tag?

Comment: It's [generally off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on Stack Overflow. (See #4) You can try [su]

Comment: Asked on [Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/838171/auto-fill-find-bar-with-highlighted-text)